# Failing to compile audio/teamspeak3-server with FreeBSD poudriere system

Tags: freebsd

I've a Poudriere server to keep local binary packages to all of our servers. A request for TeamSpak software was done and I was trying to create the binary package for installation using Poudriere.

But during the build process it fails because the license of TeamSpark must be confirmed but in a batch installation we are unable to do this.

There's a way to solve this issue and create a binary package?

The error I'm receiving is:

```
====>> [04] Finished build of audio/teamspeak3-server: Ignored: License teamspeak 
needs confirmation, but BATCH is defined
```

And at the end of process:

```
====>> Ignored ports: audio/teamspeak3-server
```

So the port isn't broken, it was just ignored.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to automatically override the `IGNORE` directive in the Makefile, you can however edit the Makefile manually and remove the IGNORE directive (it's lines 24-26 of the Makefile). It would be a license conflict for FreeBSD to distribute the port this way, but since you've already accepted the terms of the license you don't need to manually accept them at build time.

Note: this answer kind of sucks because you'd have to re-edit the Makefile every time you update your poudriere ports tree. Send a love letter to TeamSpeak if their licensing irks you as much as I suspect.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but it didn't worked. I've remove the lines from /usr/ports/audio/teamspeak3-server/Makefile and the error still persists.

Comment: Is that where Poudiere is keeping it's copy of the ports tree? It doesn't like to share by default.

Answer (score 0):

just remove or remark this line from bsd.licenses.mk :

```
+IGNORE=        License ${_LICENSE} needs confirmation, but BATCH is defined
```